# How to set DialogTitle to Typography Variant h5?

Tags: material-ui

I currently have lots of dialogs and want to change `DialogTitle` to have `Typography` `h5` heading. Currently this works:

```
 <DialogTitle>
        <Typography variant="h5">Create Exercise</Typography>
 </DialogTitle>
```

But I want this to be applied to all dialogs without having to add use the typography component. I also have tried the following with createTheme, but this does not change the fontSize.

```
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiDialogTitle: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            // Set this to h5
            fontSize: "1.5rem",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the DialogTitle component as mention below

```
import MuiDialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
});

const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
    const { children, classes, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
            <Typography variant="h5">{children}</Typography>
        </MuiDialogTitle>
    );
});

export default DialogTitle;
```

use this component as `DialogTitle`, even you can modify the style and also able to add extra component into DialogTitle, like closing icon or some secondary title.